# How to POST the file type to PHP using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML file that uploads an image to the designated folders and subfolders. The problem that I'm facing is that I'm unable to POST the form data to the PHP. Below is the code.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <!--<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="offline.js"></script>-->

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" name="viewport" content="width=200, charset=utf-8, initial-scale=1.4, maximum-scale=1.4, minimum-scale=1.4"/>
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <!--[if IE]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
      article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
      menu, nav, section { display: block; }
    </style>
    <script>
    function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(300)
                        .height(340);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }


    }
   </script>
    <script> 
     $("form#form").submit(function(){
                     var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                        $.ajax({
                            url : 'login.php',
                            type: "POST",
                            data : formData,
                            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                            {
                                //success 
                            }
                        });
                });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" method="POST">
      <input type="file" required id="image" name="image" onChange="readURL(this);" />
      <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" /><br/><br/>
      <button>Submit</button>



        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
    {
  // image upload from html



        session_start();
        $_SESSION['str'];// this is the target where the image is supposed to be stored. 
        $_SESSION['img'];// used to rename the image. 
        $image = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        echo "$image";  // added to see if the image is being received in the PHP or not.     

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str'].$_SESSION['img']);
echo "Upload Success";
}
```

What I'm trying to do is: once the option pops up to choose a file I have a function readURL that shows the preview of the image that needs to be uploaded. Then when the user presses the SUBMIT button it should call another  that POST the form data to PHP. But the other  is not sending the form data to the PHP. Kindly suggest what to do.

Comment: just like `success` handler, add an `error` handler to display errors. After `var formData;` add `console.debug(formData);` and check whether `$(this)[0]` is correct.

Comment: there is no `$('form#files')`, its supposed to be `$('form#form')` from your code

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky I even tried that but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this Js

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

<!-----Add this dev After ----->
<input type="file"  id="image" name="img" />
<div id="dvPreview"></div>


    $(function () {
        $("#image").change(function () {
            $("#dvPreview").html("");
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
            if (regex.test($(this).val().toLowerCase())) {
                if ($.browser.msie && parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version) <= 9.0) {
                    $("#dvPreview").show();
                    $("#dvPreview")[0].filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = $(this).val();
                }
                else {
                    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                        $("#dvPreview").show();
                        $("#dvPreview").append("<img />");
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            $("#dvPreview img").attr("src", e.target.result);
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
                    } else {
                        alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                alert("Please upload a valid image file.");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script>
  function readURL(input) {
      if(navigator.onLine){ 
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(300)
                .height(340);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
   }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I want to add this navigator.onLine to the other Script as i want people to see the preview but cannot upload the picture unless the internet is working

Comment: check the condition inside  $(".test").click(function(){});

Comment: Thanks. It works now. The other thing is, is it possible to trigger the submit automatically when the navigator.onLine is true?

Comment: No. It doesnt work automatically. When i try to press the submit button and navigator.onLine is false it alerts me offline but it doesnt upload the image automatically when the navigator.onLine is true

Answer (score 1):

100% Working Try This.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" action="" method="post">
        <input type="file"  id="image" name="img" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" /><br/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="upload" onclick="javascript:uploadInage();" />
    </form>


<script type="text/javascript">
        function uploadInage()
        {
        var file_data = $('#image').prop('files')[0];   
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('file', file_data);

            $.ajax({
                url: "file.php",
                dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function (result) {
                        alert(result)

                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

**file.php**

```
    <?php

    $imagePath = "uploads/";
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    $extension = end($temp);

    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $time = time();
    move_uploaded_file($filename, $imagePath . $time . '.' . $extension);    
   echo "File Uploade";
   exit;
 ?>
```

**NOte**:make folder **uploads**

Comment: Thanks a lot Dev. But if i use this code, i am unable to use the script for the preview of the image

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 function readURL(input) {     
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(300)
                .height(340);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
   uploadfunc();
  }

</script>
<script> 
function uploadfunc(){  
     if(!navigator.onLine){ 
        alert('You are offline');
        return false;   
    }else{
     var formData = new FormData();
     var info_file_data = $('#imageid').prop('files')[0];
     console.log(info_file_data);
      formData.append('info_file', info_file_data);
     $.ajax({
          url: 'login.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
          dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          data: formData,                         
          type: 'post',
          success: function(php_script_response){
            location.reload();
          }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nope. It doesnt work. I have already tried this before. No image is uploaded automatically. Can we set the property of the BUTTON to keep trigerring itself after every single second.

Comment: download js and css and include in your html. if you are offline the script not works. please check.

Comment: @dev your file upload code works perfectly but it stops the usage of the script used to preview the image.

Comment: @vel I downloaded and added into the html but still no automatic uploading of the image

Comment: Do you want to upload the image on submit button click?

Comment: @vel yeah.. exactly. But only when the navigator.onLine is true other it should show a message of "OFFLINE"

Comment: @vel For example, i want to keep the button inactive when there is no internet connection and when the internet connection is back, it should appear active. For reference, what happens in whatsapp when you dont have internet connection, the SEND button is inactive, right? and when internet connection is back it appears active and you are able to send the messages or images

Comment: @vel or in other word. Can i add an auto Click feature to an <input type="button"/> after a regular interval.

Comment: @velWow.. Awesome. This works fine but now the user wont be able to see the preview when they are online. Its uploaded to the designated place automatically

Comment: remove this line location.reload();

Comment: @vel Yes.. this works perfectly. Kindly share your facebook profile or linked in Profile.

Comment: @vel I want to add a feature that shows the image is being uploaded. I mean something like a bar showing the percentage and it is done it say upload successful

Comment: use some jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="offline.js"></script>-->

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
<meta name="author" content="Hege Refsnes">

<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
<script>
function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(300)
                    .height(340);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
 }
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function (){
        $(".test").click(function(){
             var formData = new FormData();
             var info_file_data = $('#imageid').prop('files')[0];
             console.log(info_file_data);
              formData.append('info_file', info_file_data);
             $.ajax({
                  url: 'login.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
                  dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false,
                  data: formData,                         
                  type: 'post',
                  success: function(php_script_response){
                   console.log(php_script_response);
                    return;
                  }
                });
        });
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" method="POST">
     <input type="file" required id="imageid" name="image" onChange="readURL(this);" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" /><br/><br/>
     <input type="button" class="test" value="submit"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>



<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
     if(!empty($_FILES["info_file"]["name"])){
     $target_dir        = "upload/";
     $target_file   = $target_dir .date('Ymdmsh')."_".basename($_FILES["info_file"]["name"]);
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['info_file']['tmp_name'], $target_file);
 }
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: what are the form datas?

Comment: @vel just the images.

Comment: @vel there is no error in the console. But still the image is not being uploaded to the designated location.

Comment: you didnt write code to upload. you sending only name. not a file.

Comment: @vel I am sending the file to be uploaded from the PHP. I have edited my question with the PHP code. Kindly look at it.

Comment: @vel Are you aware of navigator.onLine feature? I want to use it in the second script. I mean if the browser is not online the image should not be uploaded and should alert "You are offline".

Comment: if(navigator.onLine){ }

Comment: I know this, but i am a bit confused. Where to use that if(navigator.onLine){}. Coz i tried it a couple of places but it didnt work